# Find Android Phone Contacts Timestamp

Tags: android, android-contacts

Is there any way by which we can get the timestamp i.e the time at which a contact was added to the phonebook?

I could not see any option for the same in the Peoples or Phones class/interface

Comment: I saw an app that claimed to do that: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.blackswanhunter.android.recentcontacts

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such field in new `ContactContracts`. There is [`LAST_TIME_CONTACTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#LAST_TIME_CONTACTED) fields though, maybe it can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Yea believe d same...but probably  i there any other way to know when it was added?